# Ipython 0.12 bad status line. What does this message mean

Tags: ipython

My IPython parallel program crashed at yesterday midnight. Below is the error message. I do not know what does this message exactly mean? How can I trace the exception? What does the message "BadStatusLine" mean?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg/IPython/parallel/client/view.py", line 597, in execute
    return self._really_apply(util._execute, args=(code,), block=block, targets=targets)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _really_apply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg/IPython/parallel/client/view.py", line 59, in sync_results
    ret = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _really_apply
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg/IPython/parallel/client/view.py", line 48, in save_ids
    ret = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg/IPython/parallel/client/view.py", line 535, in _really_apply
    return ar.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg/IPython/parallel/client/asyncresult.py", line 104, in get
    raise self._exception
IPython.parallel.error.CompositeError: one or more exceptions from call to method: _execute
[11:apply]: BadStatusLine: ''
[12:apply]: BadStatusLine: ''
[13:apply]: BadStatusLine: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

[BadStatusLine](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html?highlight=badstatusline#httplib.BadStatusLine) is an error from httplib.   IPython is not raising this error, *your code* on the engines is.  IPython propagates your errors up from the engines to your client.  What does your code do?  If it is fetching things from the network, some of those requests are failing with an error code httplib does not understand.